# what does self refer to in Property class creating code?

Tags: python

In the below code that emulates property creation code:

```
class Property:
    "Emulate PyProperty_Type() in Objects/descrobject.c"

    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset
        self.fdel = fdel
        if doc is None and fget is not None:
            doc = fget.__doc__
        self.__doc__ = doc

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.fget is None:
            raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
        return self.fget(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self.fset is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
        self.fset(obj, value)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        if self.fdel is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't delete attribute")
        self.fdel(obj)

    def getter(self, fget):
        return type(self)(fget, self.fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)

    def setter(self, fset):
        return type(self)(self.fget, fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)

    def deleter(self, fdel):
        return type(self)(self.fget, self.fset, fdel, self.__doc__)
```

in `__get__`, `self` is the instance of the property class?

Also, what does `obj` refer to? Why is `obj` passed to `self.fget`?

When I test it I get the following error:

```
class A:
    func = Property(fget=func)
a = A()
a.func

TypeError: 'Property' object is not callable
```

How does it work then if it's not callable? I was under the impression that when defining a decorator as an instance you need to make sure it implements the `__call__` method?

What am I missing?

Comment: `func = Property(fget=func)` should raise an `NameError`, unless you have previously defined the name `func`.

Comment: "in `__get__`, `self` is the instance of the property class?" Yes, `self` (i.e. argument 0) always refers to the instance of the class the method is defined in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is the instance of `Property` itself. Its main purpose is to simply hold references to the getter, setter, and/or deleter so that you can call them when the property is accessed. When those functions are called, *they* get a reference to the object from which the property was accessed, so in `a.func`, `self` is the instance of `Property` and `obj` is `a`.

---

The `Property` instance itself doesn't need to be callable, because it's not what gets called. `Property.__get__` only returns self if you access it from the *class*, not an instance of the class. The built-in `property` works the same way.

```
>>> class A:
...   func = property(lambda self: 3)
...
>>> A.func
<property object at 0x10a33bb88>
>>> A().func
3
```

`func` is a class attribute whose value is an instance of `property`. The result of accessing the attribute differs depending on whether you look it up on the class itself or an instance of the class.

When accessed via the class, you get back the `property` itself.

```
A.func == A.__dict__['func'].__get__(None, A)
       == A.__dict__['func']
```

When accessed via an instance, you get back the result of calling the original function passed to `property`.

```
a = A()
a.func == A.__dict__['func'].__get__(a, A)
       == A.__dict__['func'].fget(a)
       == (lambda self: 3)(a)
       == 3
```